# 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to install sip for pyqt4, I have followed the installation instructions but when I want to execute the `make` command I get this error:
`'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I don't know why it's not working when I have followed the instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know if "make" is in fact installed on your system?  What OS are you running on?  Do you know what "make" is or if/why it would or would not exist on your system?

Comment: @CryptoFool Unfortunately I have no idea what 'make' is. I'm using windows 10

Comment: Darn.  Unfortunately, I don't know Windows.  On Mac and Linux, `make` is a tool that has existed since the early days of Unix to automate the steps necessary to build and package software, both applications and libraries.  What is likely going on is that there is part of sip, probably in C/C++, that needs to be compiled, and `make` is needed to do this.  `make` is usually installed as part of a set of tools, often centered around C/C++ development.  You might end up needing to install those too.  I bet someone will come along  who can help you on Windows.

Comment: @CryptoFool Thank you for the insight, at least I know where to look.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Comment: I re-read the link @JohnColeman gave.  I then deleted my original comment on it.  if you're willing to install and use Chocolatey, which is the simple summary of what that link says to do, you might get to the promised land without too much fuss.  Best of luck!

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "install sip for pyqt4"? Note that if you already have PyQt4, then sip should already be there. Besides that, consider that PyQt4 is **very** old, and there's the possibility that even if you successfully manage to install C++, there could be some problems compiling anyway: it has been considered obsolete and unsupported for more than 5 years and trying to build very old source code could potentially fail (especially for a library like Qt is, which use very complex building mechanisms). Are you completely sure you cannot use PyQt5?

Comment: @musicamante I want to install PyQt4, but I read that I first have to install sip.

Comment: I want to make the django2exe[https://github.com/kiburualex/django2exe] compatible with python37

Comment: Check in it's issues [Plans to Python 3.4+ support ? #2] someone says it manage to work, so I want to try it

Comment: @DreadDoc From what I can see, there's only one file (`run.py`) that actually needs PyQt. Honestly I'd first try to port it to PyQt5, as doing it, if successful, is certainly a better option than trying to install C++ on your own and probably get a headache for the distribution/package management you'd probably face later, especially considering that you didn't even know what `make` is until half of an hour ago...